# pip unable to install package even though it is present on pypi server

Tags: python, numpy, pip, pypi, pypiserver

I am trying to install NumPy package by doing

```
pip install numpy==1.19.2
```

after I installed and activated a virtual environment

but I am getting an error

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy==1.19.2 (from versions: 1.3.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.10.0, 1.10.0.post2, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.3, 1.10.4, 1.11.0b3, 1.11.0rc1, 1.11.0rc2, 1.11.0, 1.11.1rc1, 1.11.1, 1.11.2rc1, 1.11.2, 1.11.3, 1.12.0b1, 1.12.0rc1, 1.12.0rc2, 1.12.0, 1.12.1rc1, 1.12.1, 1.13.0rc1, 1.13.0rc2, 1.13.0, 1.13.1, 1.13.3, 1.14.0rc1, 1.14.0, 1.14.1, 1.14.2, 1.14.3, 1.14.4, 1.14.5, 1.14.6, 1.15.0rc1, 1.15.0rc2, 1.15.0, 1.15.1, 1.15.2, 1.15.3, 1.15.4, 1.16.0rc1, 1.16.0rc2, 1.16.0, 1.16.1, 1.16.2, 1.16.3, 1.16.4, 1.16.5, 1.16.6, 1.17.0rc1, 1.17.0rc2, 1.17.0, 1.17.1, 1.17.2, 1.17.3, 1.17.4, 1.17.5, 1.18.0rc1, 1.18.0, 1.18.1, 1.18.2, 1.18.3, 1.18.4, 1.18.5, 1.19.0rc1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy==1.19.2
```

But it is definitely present.

[image: numpy release history]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in the version of python using which the virtual environment was created. I used the python3.5 version to create it but the minimum required python version for the numpy==1.19.2 is python3.6.
It is also given in the bottom left-hand side section in the PyPI package details page.

[image: package meta data pypi]